# How can I use accented characters in Stringstrings commands?

Tags: stringstrings

I am french and I would like to manage accented characters when using Stringstrings commands.

Here is a LaTeX Minimal Example to show you my issue :

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{stringstrings}

\begin{document}

\edef\str{Ô opiniâtre salubrité}

1 -- \str

2 -- \substring{\str}{1}{$}

\end{document}
```

When I compile, I get this :

[image]

I have tried several things, including this one :

```
\encodetoken{\str}
```

It works and then, I get : "Ô opiniâtre salubrité" but I can't intervene on the chain and modify it. The string seems frozen. For example, using a statement like this :

```
\Treatments{}{}{}{}{}{0} \substring{\str}{1}{$}
```

do not delete spaces at all.

Is there a way out of this?

Thank you very much !

Comment: TeX is just unintuitive. Be careful with edef if you don't know what it does.

Comment: Is using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX an option?

Comment: [unicode - Extract a substring from a Chinese string variable - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/431845/extract-a-substring-from-a-chinese-string-variable) / [Character replacement in unicode string - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262232/character-replacement-in-unicode-string) // (slightly related question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262232/character-replacement-in-unicode-string)

Comment: Indeed `\def` instead of `\edef` seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

As the long-ago author of `stringstrings`, I can say that the package has many limitations and is not well written.  However, to address your current situation, I would say these:  the package does not handle unicode characters, but only those constructed as `\^O opini\^atre salubrit\'e`.  Secondly, the argument to the package macros, such as `\substring` can not be a macro, but must be text.  If you have it in a macro form, you must pre-expand it, as I do in case 3 below.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{stringstrings}

\begin{document}

\edef\str{Ô opiniâtre salubrité}

1 -- \str

\def\strB{\^O opini\^atre salubrit\'e}

2 -- \substring{\^O opini\^atre salubrit\'e}{1}{$}

3 -- \expandafter\substring\expandafter{\strB}{1}{$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your code mostly works if you use `\newcommand` instead of `\edef`. Note that you should probably use `\newcommand` most of the time anyway, since it checks to make sure the command isn't already defined. Since `\str` is a fairly common 3-letter name, it seems possible that it might be defined by some package, which `\def` would overwrite.

I say *mostly* works because this is my output:

[image]

`stringstrings` doesn't seem to like the `é` character.

On the other hand, the package `xstring` has no issues with accented characters:

[image]

The commands are different. `xstring` uses `\StrMid` instead of `\substring`, and `xstring` (as far as I know) has no `$` shortcut. But you can use any number that's longer than the length of the string. `xstring` has much of the same functionality of `stringstrings` so it's likely you can switch. Package documentation is available in French as well as English: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xstring

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
%\usepackage{stringstrings}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\str}{Ô opiniâtre salubrité}

\begin{document}

1 -- \str

2 -- \StrMid{\str}{1}{40}

\end{document}
```